# Castle windsor - Unable to register a proper component with argumants

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

In a unit test I resolve an interface with sending arguments for its constructor as below:

```
var args = new { arg1 = "arg1 value", arg2 = "arg2 value" };
var component = container.Resolve<IMyDependency>(args);
```

and it works fine. But now I want to do it in constructor injection, for example in:

```
public class Foo
{
     private IMyDependency _dep;
     public Foo(IMyDependency dep) { _dep = dep; }
}
```

So, As a try I register it with `UsingFactoyMethod()` like this:

```
public class BarInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            Component.For<IMyDependency>().UsingFactoryMethod(
                () =>
                {
                    var args = new { arg1 = "arg1 value", arg2 = "arg2 value" };
                    var result = container.Resolve<IMyDependency>(args);
                    return result;
                }).LifestyleTransient());

        // + some other registerations and installs
    }
}
```

But I have still error:

> Can't create component 'namespace.MyDependency' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
>
> 'namespace.MyDependency' is waiting for the following dependencies:
>   - Parameter 'arg1' which was not provided. Did you forget to set the dependency?
>   - Parameter 'arg2' which was not provided. Did you forget to set the dependency?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try register IMyDependency implementaion with it's constructor args instead of using "UsingFactoyMethod()":

```
string someArg = "something";
container.Register(
        Component.For<IMyDependency>().ImplementedBy<MyDependencyImp>()
           .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("someArg",someArg)).LifestyleTransient());
```

Assuming MyDependencyImp constructor looks something like this:

```
public MyDependencyImp(string someArg)
{
    /....
}
```

More info [here](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/inline-dependencies.md).

Comment: I've tested it, And it gives me an error about that there is already a component for IMyDependency ;).

Comment: Maybe you've registered it in another place in your code also? If yes you should try replace it.

Comment: Well, as I can check, it's only registered in `BarInstaller` and with above code two times, But how to replace it?

Comment: Just try to put code as I suggested instead of the old IMyDependency registration you should add dependson for every constructor argument with it's name and value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you register IMyDependency anywhere else? It's tough to say what's wrong until you post the actual code.

This should work:

```
container.Register(
        Component.For<IMyDependency>().UsingFactoryMethod(
            () =>
            {
                return new MyDependency("arg1 value", "arg2 value");
            }).LifestyleTransient());
```

Comment: As I check, `MyDependency` is registered in some other registrations also.